# Reading Windows encoded files in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, utf-8

I have been struggling for an embarrassingly long time now to correctly read Umlaute from a Windows encoded file. The file is saved using the Windows-1252 codec and consists of one single line:

```
123 äöü 456
```

My simple test program to isolate the behavior I don't understand is;

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextCodec>
#include <QByteArray>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

  QStringList ids;
  QFile inputFile("test.txt");
  QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1252");
  if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
  {
     QTextStream in(&inputFile);
     while (!in.atEnd())
     {
        QByteArray line = inputFile.readLine();
        QString string = codec->toUnicode(line);
        qDebug() << string;
     }
     inputFile.close();
  }
  else
      qDebug() << "Cannot open file";

  return a.exec();
}
```

The console output is:

```
"123 ??? 456\r\n"
```

So all the Umlaute get eaten up.

I am running this in Linux, the terminal emulator is set to use UTF-8. What can possibly go wrong here.

Comment: I would create a test case that is completely portable. At this point it's hard to say what's wrong: is the file encoded wrong? Is the codec not working? Is the debug output not working? Instead of using a file, use a `QBuffer` that you pre-populate with hardcoded data in proper encoding. Then use a codec to convert it to a `QString` and verify that proper characters are there using their codepoints. Finally, dump it to debug output and see if the output is correct.

Comment: Inspect the `string` variable in memory with a debugger, or with `QMessageBox`, before writing it to the console.  Does `string` contain the umlautes correctly? If so, then they are getting lost by the console.

Comment: QIODevice::readLine says that it reads ASCII text, so in line with what the others are saying, make sure that "line" actually contains the data you expect before attempting to do any conversions. Dump that out in hex, for instance. If that's the case, then you may need to open the file as a binary file instead of a text file, read the data, and then convert it using the codec.

Comment: Thanks guys, and once again I was too stupid to debug correctly. The problem was indeed my terminal emulator, the data in the debugger is correct and it also works when I write it to a file.